# How to write a script in AHK that pastes a text, waits one minute, then pastes again?

Tags: wait, autohotkey, repeat

How to write a script in AHK that pastes a text, waits one minute, then pastes again?

AHK=AutoHotKey

Not for spamming, it's for one of my own web projects.

I should specify: the script needs to paste a text, press return, wait one minute then paste again. If it doesn't press return it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

SetTimer is better than sleep for something like this.

```
#Persistent

; Put this wherever you want, like inside a hotkey
; Either set the clipboard to some text, or just remove this
; to use what's already there
Clipboard = This is some text to paste
SendInput ^v{Enter}
last_text := Clipboard
SetTimer, RePaste, 60000
return

RePaste:
; The clipboard can change in a minute, right?
; so we use the text we had before
tmp := clipboard
Clipboard := last_text
SendInput ^v{Enter}

; And restore what the user had
Clipboard := tmp
return

; Put this somewhere, like in a hotkey, to turn off the timer
SetTimer, RePaste, off
```

Comment: I updated the original question. The script needs to press return.

Comment: Good work guys, much appreciated. If you are interested in developing for us, please check out http://www.github.com/folly

Answer (score 1):

```
#NoEnv
Loop
{
SendInput, ^v
Sleep, 60000
}
Capslock::ExitApp
```

Press caps lock to stop pasting. For text defined in code:

```
#NoEnv
Loop
{
SendInput, This is the text I want to send{Enter}
Sleep, 60000
}
Capslock::ExitApp
```

Comment: Could you edit the code with an example text so I know which part to replace. I guess ^v would paste from clipboard but I would like the text to be defined in the code.

Comment: Works but only for short texts, long texts don't seem to work. Do I need to add some special signs like quotation marks for longer texts spanning over several line breaks?

Comment: I updated the original question. The script needs to press return.

Comment: Good work guys, much appreciated. If you are interested in developing for us, please check out http://www.github.com/folly